# como puede guarda una fecha ingresa por el usuario codigo php,

Tags: html5, phpmyadmin

tengo este form pero nose como hacer pedir y dividir la fecha en php para guardarla en la base de datos.

```
<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
    Fecha <input type="date" name="fecha"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que tienes en `guardar.php`, no importa si no funciona o está incompleto, solo necesitamos un poco de tu parte para poder ayudar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! porque querrias dividir la fecha?

Comment: la pregunta no es comprensible a nivel de redacción

Comment: Mira tambien la etiqueta [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

Answer (score 0):

mira con este código obtienes la fecha ingresada por el usuario cuándo él le de al botón de enviar, además con el método explode, puedes dividir esa fecha, y almacenarla en la variable lista, donde en la posición 0 estará el día, en la 1 el mes y en la 2 el año. Espero seas lo que buscas, por favor sé mas específico la próxima vez :)

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {      
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $lista = explode( '-', $fecha, 3 );
     }      
?>
```